# laravel5 composer install error zend guar loader

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.1, zend-guard

i try to install Laravel 5.1:

> php composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist

and i have got this:

```
Error Output: Zend Guard Loader requires Zend Engine API version 220090626.
  The Zend Engine API version 220121212 which is installed, is newer.
  Contact Zend Technologies at http://www.zend.com/ for a later version of Ze
  nd Guard Loader.
```

Comment: There is probably something wrong with your php.ini file - It might be searching for the wrong version. Would need more info on this.. You should probably look at this file and see which version is running or it might be found by creating a separate .php file on your server and run `phpinfo()`

Comment: PHP Version 5.5.28,
Zend Extension  220121212
Zend Extension Build  API220121212,NTS
PHP Extension Build  API20121212,NTS

Comment: I reconfig php once again and now it works, thanks :)

Comment: I made my comment into an answer. If I solved this problem for you, please mark it as solved so that others can learn from this :)! Glad the problem has been sorted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is due to a value set within the php.ini file, which is probably searching for the wrong version number.

Check that these values are pointing to the right version of ZEND, or disable ZEND Guard Loader (the later is probably not the best)..

Hope that this fixes the issue for you.